# Pandas py3 how to get a Pandas objects attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a  object which I get from df.itertuples(). In py2.7 it seemed that equivalent object had a **dict** attribute, but this seems to be missing in py3. What is the equivalent way of getting all the objects attribute's names? the py 3 way, using vars also requires a **dict** attribute.

dir(o) is working, but spits out all sorts of __ properties that I am not interested in. I am only looking to get the attributes that I gave to the object. And I may have attributes myself starting with _, so I am not looking for some sort of helper function to clean that up, but a built-in way to retrieve the attributes like **dict** does in 2.7.